# How to install 3rd party modules in Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x

Having thoroughly researched my question and tried many routes, here I am. 
the module I want is openpyxl

I have tried 
1.) extracting and copying it to the C:\Users\chuck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib
THEN pip install openpyxl
no luck.

2.) pip install in the python shell . no luck.

I have actually done this before, though on a mac and it was as easy as pip3 install openpyxl in cmd line.

Comment: if you're on Ubuntu or other Debian use apt-get install python3-pip , on RHEL systems use yum install python3-pip and then pip3 install ...

Comment: on windows, and here's the thing . pip is not even recognized as a command by my pc.

Comment: Just get setuptools for windows from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: Try `python -m pip install openpyxl`.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try and copy it to C:\Users\chuck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages ?
It should work I am not sure though. Try it.